# Is every positive Borel measure on a compact Hausdorff space bounded?

Tags: measure-theory

In the Remark to the Theorem 3.27 of Rudin's Functional Analysis, it says

> If $\nu$ is any positive Borel measure on $Q$, then some scalar multiple of $\nu$ is a probability measure.

Here, $Q$ is assumed to be a compact Hausdorff space in Theorem 3.27.

I am not certain if $\nu(Q)<\infty$ for every positive Borel measure $\nu$ on $Q$.
I guess that $\nu$ should be assumed to be also bounded.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What about the standard Lebesgue measure on $\bar {\bf R}$ ?

Comment: I do not have Rudin's FA at hand, but I assume that either he is making the implicit assumption that it is bounded or it is just not correct. We can give infinite mass to our favorite point, mass one to our second favorite point and zero to everything else. This "linear combination" of dirac deltas is a Borel measure and clearly not a scalar multiple of a probability measure.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for your answer. Knowing that there is a positive Borel measure that is not bounded on a compact Hausdorff space, I guess that the measure should be assumed to be also bounded. Indeed, this additional assumption does not contradict the message of the remark that says that Theorem 3.27 can be extended to a real or complex measure that can be decomposed into bounded positive Borel measures.